# Why is set(None) invalid in python

Tags: python, types, set

```
>>> set(None)
*** TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

is a problem but not this:

```
>>> a=set()
>>> a.add(None)
```

Why?

Comment: I tend to agree with you. None should be considered the empty element and simply not added without throwing an error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the error message tells you, `set()` expects an iterable.

```
set([None])
```

Note: the same is true for `list`, `tuple`, ...

Comment: Been asking stupid questions all day long, where's my cigarette

Comment: Wasn't a stupid question imo.  I learned something anyway!  Didn't know NoneType was hashable until I looked into this question, so thanks @EknathIyer :).

Answer (score 4):

Because the set initializer takes an object that must be iterable, but add() will take any element as long as its hashable.  Since NoneType is not iterable, it raises an exception.

> **class** `set([iterable])`
>   Return a new set or frozenset object whose elements are taken from iterable. 
>   The elements of a set must be
>   hashable. To represent sets of sets, the inner sets must be frozenset
>   objects. If iterable is not specified, a new empty set is returned.
>
> `add(elem)` Add element elem to the set.
>
> **iterable**
>  An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as list,
>   str, and tuple) and some non-sequence types like dict and file and
>   objects of any classes you define with an `__iter__()` or `__getitem__()`
>   method. Iterables can be used in a for loop and in many other places
>   where a sequence is needed (zip(), map(), ...). When an iterable
>   object is passed as an argument to the built-in function iter(), it
>   returns an iterator for the object. This iterator is good for one pass
>   over the set of values. When using iterables, it is usually not
>   necessary to call iter() or deal with iterator objects yourself. The
>   for statement does that automatically for you, creating a temporary
>   unnamed variable to hold the iterator for the duration of the loop.
>   See also iterator, sequence, and generator.

```
In [18]: hash(None)
Out[18]: 39746304

In [19]: iter(None)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/jon/<ipython console> in <module>()    
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

In [21]: dir(None)
Out[21]: 
['__class__',  
 '__delattr__',  
 '__doc__', 
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__', 
 '__new__', 
 '__reduce__', 
 ...
 '__subclasshook__']

In [22]: dir([])
Out[22]:
[...  
 '__hash__',
 '__getitem__',
 ...  
 '__iter__',
```